# Redux-Saga pass headers to axios.post call

Tags: django, reactjs, jwt, redux-saga

I am having some difficulties with `redux-saga`. I have the following saga:

`createPostSaga`:

```
function* createPostSaga(action) {
  const token = yield select(selectToken);
  const headerParams = {
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
  };
  console.log(token, headerParams);
  try {
    yield call(axios.post, "/posts/", action.payload, headerParams);
    yield call(getPosts());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

As you can see I am selecting my token, and putting into an object with key `Authorization` and value `JWT ${token}`, my API is still responding with `401 unauthorized`, but it must be an issue with this call because I can replicate this call in Postman and it goes through fine:

[image: Postman Request]

Does anyone see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create a fetch function and use it inside `.call`.

```
function* createPostSaga(action) {
  const token = yield select(selectToken);
  const headerParams = {
    "Authorization": `JWT ${token}`
  };

  const apiCall = () => {
    return axios.post('/posts', {
      action.payload // only if not an object. Otherwise don't use outer {},
    },
    headerParams: headerParams,
   ).then(response => response.data)
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
  }

  console.log(token, headerParams);
  try {
    yield call(apiCall);
    yield call(getPosts());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: its now saying `elativeURL.replace is not a function` instead of 401 unauthorized

Comment: I did that because of [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/611) but the same message comes up.

Comment: @CHBresser sorry, forgot about axios options order. Edited answer,

Comment: just check if Auth header was send. It's only related with axios request options correctness.

Comment: ok I have the call working, but now the promise that apiCall returns is causing a problem with `call()`, and giving this error: `uncaught at check call: argument [object Promise] is not a function`

Comment: @CHBresser you need to resolve promise inside `apiCall`. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the function like this.

```
function* createPostSaga(action) {
  const token = yield select(selectToken);
  const headerParams = {
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
  };
  console.log(token, headerParams);
  try {
    yield call(axios.post, "/posts/", action.payload, {headers:headerParams});
    yield call(getPosts());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```